# change background images using mouse wheel plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseevent, mousewheel

I am trying to change the background image of a page when a uses mouse wheel scroll/scrolldown. Something [like this page here](https://www.chelseacollective.com/home).

I have three different background images that I wish to change (i.e. increment when the user scrolls down/decrement when the user scrolls up).

[See jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1nrL5gv1/1/) (which isn't really working as hoped).

Please also see code below.

I hope it is clear what I am trying to achieve. If not please let me know and I can provide further information.

**CSS**

```
.bgImage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

body, html, #scene, .bgImage {
  height: 100%; 
}

.home{
  background: url("http://cdn3-www.wrestlezone.com/assets/uploads/gallery/ric-flair/gettyimages-93353438.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.brett {
  background: url("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-69o3lsK5MrQ/ThhlOTxGQlI/AAAAAAAAEfY/e0AJF-6sKBw/s1600/bret_hart_-_bret_hart_74.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hulk{
background: url("https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M44755b5d2bade01af176621c77ebe279o2&pid=15.1&P=0&w=300&h=300") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bgImage"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var pages = ['home','brett','hulk'];
var page = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.bgImage').on('mousewheel', function (e) {
        if (e.deltaY>0) {
            page += 1;
            if(page >= pages.length){
                return;
            }else{
                jQuery('.bgImage').addClass(pages[page]);
            }
        } else {
            page -= 1;
            jQuery('.bgImage').removeClass(pages[page]);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat I can tell you that you'll probably need a more robust scrolling framework in order to emulate the site you linked. Try checking out [scrollmagic.io](http://www.scrollmagic.io) for ideas on how to execute this. One way to look at it is you are essentially capturing scrolling and applying them to a "timeline" of events, if you will.

To get your example working, check out this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1nrL5gv1/20/

One important thing I added was the removal of all of the existing classes before you apply a new one. This way, only the most recent image will show up and you won't have to worry about css specificity/order.

`function cleanUpBg() {
    for(i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        bgEl.removeClass(pages[i]);
    }
}`

I also added a timeout so you can actually trigger one image change at a time. Again, I highly recommend checking out existing scroll libraries, as they will allow you get into a project like this much more quickly.

Comment: this is good, but if scroll quickly it changes more than one image per scroll

Comment: @phantom yes agreed, I added a slight timeout bandaid, but ideally it should be three different divs with some sort of delta threshold/constraint logic to allow smooth fading. Tried to keep it within op's original set up, but can definitely expand upon it they desire.